# Fetching data with Graphql in Gatsby-React class component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Here is the class component in Gatsby-React containing hard-coded data that works fine:

```
import React from "react";

class ExmpClassComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);

    // hard-coded data:
    this.state = {
      myData: [
        {
          itemID: 1,
          name: "Isaac Newton",
          bio: [
            'Sir Isaac Newton PRS (25 December 1642 – 20 March 1726/27) was an English mathematician, physicist, astronomer, theologian, and author (described in his own day as a "natural philosopher") who is widely recognised as one of the most influential scientists of all time, and a key figure in the scientific revolution. His book Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica (Mathematical Principles of Natural Philosophy), first published in 1687, laid the foundations of classical mechanics. Newton also made seminal contributions to optics, and shares credit with Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz for developing the infinitesimal calculus.'
          ]
        },
        {
          itemID: 2,
          name: "Nikola Tesla",
          bio: [
            "Nikola Tesla (10 July 1856 – 7 January 1943) was one of the few greatest physicists ever - most likely the greatest one of all times.",
            "Tesla's work was systematically obstructed by Thomas Edison.",
            "American scientific community decided to decorate the great physicists Nikola Tesla with the award that on itself had the name of the person who truly envied Tesla and who could hardly be considered a scientist at all - IEEE Edison Medal."
          ]
        },
        {
          itemID: 3,
          name: "Albert Einstein",
          bio: [
            'Albert Einstein (14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955) was a German-born theoretical physicist who developed the theory of relativity, one of the two pillars of modern physics (alongside quantum mechanics). His work is also known for its influence on the philosophy of science. He is best known to the general public for his mass–energy equivalence formula E = mc^2, which has been dubbed "the world\'s most famous equation". He received the 1921 Nobel Prize in Physics "for his services to theoretical physics, and especially for his discovery of the law of the photoelectric effect", a pivotal step in the development of quantum theory.'
          ]
        }
      ],
      currentDetails: {
        title: "Select a name in the sidebar list to learn more.",
        body: []
      }
    };
  }

  clickHandler(ev) {
    let listItems = ev.target.parentNode.children;
    for (let item of listItems) {
      if (item.hasAttribute("id")) {
        item.removeAttribute("id");
      }
    }
    ev.target.setAttribute("id", "clickedItem");

    for (let singleObj of this.state.myData) {
      if (ev.target.textContent === singleObj.name) {
        this.setState({
          currentDetails: {
            title: singleObj.name,
            body: singleObj.bio
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-data">
        <ul>
          {this.state.myData.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li onClick={this.clickHandler} key={index}>
                {item.name}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <div className="bio">
          <h3>{this.state.currentDetails.title}</h3>
          {this.state.currentDetails.body.map((item, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{item}</p>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ExmpClassComp;
```

but, when I want to use Graphql to fetch the data:

```
import React from "react";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

class ExmpClassComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      myData: useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query MyAppQueryList {
          file(relativePath: { eq: "appData.json" }) {
            childrenAppDataJson {
              name
              bio
            }
          }
        }
      `),
      currentDetails: {
        title: "Select a name in the list to learn more.",
        body: []
      }
    };
  }

  clickHandler(ev) {
    let listItems = ev.target.parentNode.children;
    for (let item of listItems) {
      if (item.hasAttribute("id")) {
        item.removeAttribute("id");
      }
    }
    ev.target.setAttribute("id", "clickedItem");

    for (let singleObj of this.state.myData) {
      if (ev.target.textContent === singleObj.name) {
        this.setState({
          currentDetails: {
            title: singleObj.name,
            body: singleObj.bio
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-data">
        <ul>
          {this.state.myData.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li onClick={this.clickHandler} key={index}>
                {item.name}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <div className="bio">
          <h3>{this.state.currentDetails.title}</h3>
          {this.state.currentDetails.body.map((item, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{item}</p>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ExmpClassComp;
```

I get this error message:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

May I please get the help with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[`useStaticQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/) is a [custom-hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook), therefore it can be called only within a **functional component**.

> Gatsby v2.1.0 introduces `useStaticQuery`, a new Gatsby feature that provides the ability to use a **React Hook** to query with GraphQL at build time.

In gatsby, to fetch a static query with **class components** (like in your case), you need to use [`StaticQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/).

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

const Header = ({ data }) => (
  <header>
    <h1>{data.site.siteMetadata.title}</h1>
  </header>
)

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
          query {
            site {
              siteMetadata {
                title
              }
            }
          }
        `}
        render={data => <Header data={data} {...props} />}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

In addition, you may want to use [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/) which will inject the data to components props.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I changed class to function component, imported { useState } and it works like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
import { useState } from "react";

function DemoAppList() {
  const fetchedData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query MyAppQueryList {
      file(relativePath: { eq: "appData.json" }) {
        childrenAppDataJson {
          name
          bio
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  const dataArr = fetchedData.file.childrenAppDataJson;

  const [currentContent, setContent] = useState({
    title: "Select a name in the sidebar list to learn more.",
    body: []
  });

  const clickHandler = ev => {
    let listItems = ev.target.parentNode.children;
    for (let item of listItems) {
      if (item.hasAttribute("id")) {
        item.removeAttribute("id");
      }
    }
    ev.target.setAttribute("id", "clickedItem");

    for (let singleObj of dataArr) {
      if (ev.target.textContent === singleObj.name) {
        setContent({
          title: singleObj.name,
          body: singleObj.bio
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app-data">
      <ul>
        {dataArr.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li onClick={clickHandler} key={index}>
              {item.name}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <div className="bio">
        <h3>{currentContent.title}</h3>
        {currentContent.body.map((item, index) => {
          return <p key={index}>{item}</p>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default DemoAppList;
```